# Table has margin, but everywhere it says it's 0

Tags: css

I can't change margin of the table even though it says it's already 0, but as you can see on the screenshot it's not. Anyone knows if it's some kind of a bug?

Here is the code:

```
    table
      template(
        v-for="{ name, link, icon, children = null } in menu"
      )
        tr
          td
            b-img(:src="icon")
          td
            b-link(:to="link") 
              | {{ name }}
              
        template(v-if="children")
          tr
          tr(v-for="c in children")
            td
            td.child
              b-link(
                :href="c.link"
              ) {{ c.name }}
```

and relevant CSS:

```
  table {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    
    td {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      overflow: hidden;
      
      &:first-child {
        max-width: 50px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      img {
        margin-right: 25px
      }

      &.child {
        padding-left: 20px
      } 
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code here in a snippet and not screen shots. How could we begin to help you with what you posted?

Comment: True, I updated my post with relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: your code is not enough to demonstrate your issue, has parent's table a padding, did you reset body margin, else. however the few info you lt us see cannot reproduce your issue. something is missing that you are not telling.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure there is no margin on your table. `display: table` behaves like a block element. You could say they use 100% of the available width given by its parent.
See [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-level)

I think the fastest solution (maybe with complications) would be to give your table `display: inline-table`.

On the other hand: if you are planning to use it as a menu container then maybe check out something like *flexbox*, take a look at this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `margin: 0` is crossed out when you inspect the element means that it is being overridden somewhere else in the CSS. The quick and dirty fix would be uncomment the `margin: 0` line in the HTML and add `!important` onto the end of that line.

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't look like you have any styling on your code. Your inline-css seems to be commented out, and the screenshot with the margin:0 crossed out is showing :before and :after. Perhaps scroll up a bit in your 'styles' window to verify that there's actually a margin: 0, and then if not uncommented it (remove the /* */) from your inline styles...

Comment: Even with uncommented `margin-right: 0` it still wasn't working. I updated my question with relevant code and style.

Comment: I also updated question with uncommented styling now.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I had to to add `width: 100%` on the `table` so it will actually fill the whole div. That margin was very deceitful so I hope if someone will have similar problem they will just make sure it's full width.